# Firebase doesn't send OTP Authentication code to phone number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Villez please check this for me? I would like to do Otp authentication with Android studio Firebase (cloud firestore). The process seems correct But I do not receive the code after entering a number What I mean is that after entering the phone number and clicking on the validation button, a code should be sent to the number automatically but there I do not receive anything. Please help me to know what is wrong. Here is my code

**UPDATE :** Sorry for the delay. I ended up finding it. the only thing that was wrong was the fact that I had used a test number in the sign-in in method.Now the code is functional

Register.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.rilixtech.widget.countrycodepicker.CountryCodePicker;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String phoneNumber;
    String otpCode ;
    String verificationId;
    EditText phone,optEnter;
    Button next;
    CountryCodePicker countryCodePicker;
    PhoneAuthCredential credential;
    Boolean verificationOnProgress = false;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView state,resend;
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);

        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        optEnter = findViewById(R.id.codeEnter);
        countryCodePicker = findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        next = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        state = findViewById(R.id.state);
        resend = findViewById(R.id.resendOtpBtn);

        resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // todo:: resend OTP
            }
        });


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty() && phone.getText().toString().length() == 8) {
                    if(!verificationOnProgress){
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String phoneNum = "+"+countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCode()+phone.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("phone", "Phone No.: " + phoneNum);
                        requestPhoneAuth(phoneNum);
                    }else {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        state.setText("Logging in");
                        state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        otpCode = optEnter.getText().toString();
                        if(otpCode.isEmpty()){
                            optEnter.setError("Required");
                            return;
                        }

                        credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId,otpCode);
                        verifyAuth(credential);
                    }

                }else {
                    phone.setError("Valid Phone Required");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void requestPhoneAuth(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber,60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,this,
                new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                        super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
                        Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "OTP Timeout, Please Re-generate the OTP Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        resend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                        verificationId = s;
                        token = forceResendingToken;
                        verificationOnProgress = true;
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        next.setText("Verify");
                        next.setEnabled(true);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                        // called if otp is automatically detected by the app
                        verifyAuth(phoneAuthCredential);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register2.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }


    private void verifyAuth(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        fAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Phone Verified."+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkUserProfile();
                }else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Can not Verify phone and Create Account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            state.setText("Checking..");
            state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            checkUserProfile();
        }
    }

    private void checkUserProfile() {
        DocumentReference docRef = fStore.collection("users").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserProfil.class));
                    finish();
                }else {
                    //Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Profile Do not Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Profile Do Not Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :** Sorry for the delay. I ended up finding it. the only thing that was wrong was the fact that I had used a test number in the sign-in in method.
Now the code is functional

Comment: what is `60L` inside `verifyPhoneNumber`?

Comment: it is the methodology it seems to me, the number of seconds after which the otp will be sent I suppose

Comment: shoundn't it be integer? thrn why is a  L there

Comment: Ok . I removed the L but the code is not always sent. Please check with me

Comment: In test mode in the firebase console, it works fine. I would like the code to be sent to the number entered and not to make the choices directly in the console